# Pressing the "Enter" button to submit a form?

Tags: html, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a login form, and I'm trying to have it submit when I press the enter button (after having filled it out). I'm fine with using jQuery. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are focused on one of the fields and hit enter, it will submit. This is the default behavior for all browsers that I know of. You actually don't need the `<input type="submit" />` as others have said, but of course you *should* (and probably do).

You only need javascript if you want this behavior *without* focusing on an input, but I would strongly advise against it because no one will be expecting it. Just let users interact with the form the way they are used to, no surprises.